# I need to create a regular expression where 2 groups point to the same pattern

Tags: regex

I have 4 file names

```
ABC_ALL_20230508T050011.zip
ABC_Intra1_20230508T050011.zip
ABC_Intra2_20230508T050011.zip
ABC_INT_20230508T050011.zip
```

I am trying to create a regex that captures ExtractId, FileName and Date. The ExtractId and FileName need to capture the same values in the middle position eg 'ALL', 'Intra1', 'Intra2' or 'INT'

I currently have:

```
(?<ExtractId>[a-zA-Z]{3})_(?<FileName>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)_(?<FileDate>[0-9A-Z]{8}).*
```

and results to:

```
ExtractId = ABC
Matched
FileName = ALL
Matched
FileDate = 20230508
```

I am after:

```
ExtractId = ALL
Matched
FileName = ALL
Matched
FileDate = 20230508
```

I believe there is a way of achieving this using regex sub expression where you can have 2 groups point to the same position but I have never use it before.

Thanks

Comment: If you want ExtractId to be equal to FileName, why not doing `ExtractId = FileName` ?

Comment: You could do that with a lookahead assertion and a capture group `(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}_(?<ExtractId>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_)[a-zA-Z]{3}_(?<FileName>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)_(?<FileDate>[0-9A-Z]{8}).*` See https://regex101.com/r/1yV0Sc/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named capture group in a lookahead assertion:

```
(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}_(?<ExtractId>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_)[a-zA-Z]{3}_(?<FileName>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_(?<FileDate>[0-9A-Z]{8}).*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?=` Positive lookahead assertion

  - `[a-zA-Z]{3}_` Match 3 times a-zA-Z and then match `_`
  - `(?<ExtractId>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_` Named group *Extractid*, capture 1+ chars a-zA-Z0-9 and then match `_`
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}_` Match 3 times a-zA-Z and then match `_`
- `(?<FileName>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` Named group *FileName*, capture 1+ chars a-zA-Z0-9
- `_` Match literally
- `(?<FileDate>[0-9A-Z]{8})` Named group *FileDate*, capture 8 chars 0-9A-Z
- `.*` Match the rest of the string (if you need that, else you can omit this part)

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aIDV7k/1).

If you want to anchor the strings to the start, you can prepend `^` like:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z]{3}_(?<ExtractId>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_)[a-zA-Z]{3}_(?<FileName>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_(?<FileDate>[0-9A-Z]{8}).*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the former of the overlapping capture groups in a lookahead assertion to leave the buffer for the last overlapping capture group to match:

```
_(?=(?<ExtractId>[^_]+))(?<FileName>[^_]+)_(?<FileDate>[0-9A-Z]{8})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YhFyIn/2